# Skills Backlog Query

Tags: servicecloud, omnichannel

Is there a way to query for items in the Skills Backlog? This is the tab in Omni-supervisor that shows any work that haven't been accepted.

Answer (score 1):

From OmniChannel SOAP Api guide , the Object to query is [PendingServiceRouting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/sforce_api_objects_pendingservicerouting.htm) .

And you mentioned its for Skill based and not QueueBased so that would be your filter.

```
SELECT CapacityPercentage, Your_Fields FROM PendingServiceRouting WHERE RoutingType = 'SkillsBased'
```

Comment: PendingServiceRouting can be a pending request waiting for an agent to accept as well. How do I differentiate between the PendingServiceRoutings that are in the backlog versus the ones that are being routed to agents?

Comment: isPushed=false and IsReadyforRouting=true?

Comment: Just tried it. The values are the same for PendingServiceRouting that is routed to agents and ones in the backlog

Comment: Any insight in how you query the skills associated to that PendingServiceRouting record when using skillbased?